# Use Macro to add entities to doxygen group

Tags: c++11, macros, cmake, doxygen

In a very large code base I want to automatically add classes and functions to groups based on the project they are defined in. Luckily, I already have a compiler macro `PROJECT_NAME_EXPORTED` appended to each exported function and class:

```
enum PROJECT_NAME_EXPORTED MyEnum ....
class PROJECT_NAME_EXPORTED MyClass ....
PROJECT_NAME_EXPORTED void myFunction(int a) ....
```

The macro follows the same convention but is different for every subproject, e.g. `SOME_PROJECT_EXPORTED`, `OTHER_EXPORTED`.
So having a list of all projects I do the following in my doxygen's CMake:

```
foreach(name ${LIST_OF_PROJECTS})
    SET(DOXYGEN_PREDEFINED_MACROS "${DOXYGEN_PREDEFINED_MACROS}\"${name}_EXPORTED=(void)/** @ingroup ${name}*/\" \\ \n")
endforeach()
```

And this almost works, the classes are listed correctly but the functions are listed with two return types (the actual one and the (void) I injected above):

```
void void myFunction(int a)
```

The culprit is obviously said injected `(void)` but if I leave it out, the classes are not correctly added to the group anymore.

Is there a different "dummy" word to add here or an entirely different solution for automatically adding all entities in a project to the corresponding doxygen group?

Comment: Your class and enum are lacking a trailing semicolon.

Comment: Have you tried using `config_file` instead?

Comment: Yes, I am using a configuration file. Which settings would you recommend in config_file that solve the issue?

Comment: I would use config_file instead of the Doxygen macro, search&replace "enum (void)" and "class (void)" and give that to Doxygen.